# Visa on arrival in Egypt

Tags: egypt

We are travelling to Egypt on Sunday. My Wife is a Canadian/British citizen with a Canadian passport, but has the indefinite right of entry in it. Will she be able to get a visa on entry in Sharm El-Sheikh?

Comment: Indefinite right of entry to where? The UK?

Comment: [Egyptian embassy in Ottawa announces new visa requirement for Canadian nationals effective 1 October 2023](https://taxnews.ey.com/news/2023-1607-egyptian-embassy-in-ottawa-announces-new-visa-requirement-for-canadian-nationals-effective-1-october-2023) *On 7 September 2023, the Egyptian embassy in Ottawa announced that effective 1 October 2023, Canadian passport holders will be required to obtain entry visas from an Egyptian embassy or consulate before traveling to Egypt. They will no longer be able to obtain e-visas prior to travel or visas on arrival in Egypt.* Consult Egypt's visa policies.

Comment: @WeatherVane That sounds like an answer.

Comment: It does and doesn’t really? Yes Canadian as said but she’s also a British citizen she uses her Canadian passport which has a right of abode stamp and states that a British citizen can use another passport from another country to travel if they are of dual citizenship so going back to my unanswered question would she get a VOA if she were to go to Egypt as she is a British citizen and allowed by law to use her Canadian passport to travel as a British citizen?

Comment: If she is using a Canadian passport to travel to Egypt then she is travelling as a Canadian citizen, obviously. If she wants to travel as a British citizen she would use her British passport. Above, it says *Canadian passport holders*.

Comment: @Lespez Just because the UK allows someone to use their Canadian passport, which has a right of abode stamp, to travel as a british citizen **doesn't** mean that other countries must do the same. In this context the **right of abode** means the have the right to enter the UK as a british citizen.

Answer (score 1):

So, British citizens get [visa-free in Sharm El-Sheikh](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=gb&destination=eg), whereas [Canadian citizens don't](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=ca&destination=eg). If she wants to travel visa-free to Sharm El-Sheikh, she will have to use her British passport, at least when passing through Immigration, in and out, in Egypt.